# Please help me find what's wrong in my method to integrate polynomial in square root

Tags: integration, polynomials

Suppose I have to integrate arbitrary quadratic polynomial in square root

$$\int{\sqrt{ax^2+bx+c}}\,dx$$

And then I use $u$ substitution as this

$$u = \sqrt{-ax^2-bx-c}$$

$$ax^2+bx+(c+u^2) = 0$$

$$x = \frac{-b-\sqrt{b^2 - 4a(c+u^2)}}{2a}$$

Which means it should cancel everything out into

$$\int{\sqrt{u^2}}\,d \frac{-b-\sqrt{b^2 - 4a(c-u^2)}}{2a}$$

$$\int{u}\,d \frac{-b-\sqrt{b^2 - 4a(c-u^2)}}{2a}$$

$$\left[\frac{u^2}{2}\right]_\frac{-b-\sqrt{b^2 - 4a(c-u_0^2)}}{2a}^\frac{-b-\sqrt{b^2 - 4a(c-u_1^2)}}{2a}$$

And if this is correct, I think actually we might be able to derive this formula for both 3rd and 4th-degree polynomial? (because they also have the solution in radical)

It seems like I did something wrong here. Could anyone educate me where did I go wrong?

---

OK I have seen why it wrong now. The formula I use is incorrect. Thank you

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. Do you suggest that the integral you end up with is easier to handle? And do you ask if the formula you suggest is correct?

Comment: @mickep That's right. It seem too simple to be correct

Comment: Your approach will work only if $u$ happens to be the **derivative** of the expression following $d$.